# Javascript Parallax effect, "missing pixels"

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my code for a "parallax effect". Every time that I scroll up or down the script displaces a div 1px in the opposite direction, so, we can say that if I scroll down 300px the div will be displaced 300px up, and if we scroll up 300px the div should go back to the normal position. Here is the problem, everytime that I scroll up/down the div seems to be displaced 1 or 2 pxs from the original position.

```
 window.onscroll = function() {

        newpos = window.scrollY



        if (oldpos < newpos) {

            red.style.transform = "translateY(" + move-- + "px)";

            red.innerHTML = move;

        } else {

            red.style.transform = "translateY(" + move++ + "px)";
            red.innerHTML = move;

        }



        oldpos = window.scrollY


    }
```

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zgwx4f8v/

Comment: What is `move`? You never declared or initialised it?

Comment: Why not simply make the element `position: fixed`?

Comment: move is the distance between the top of the page and the div, move = 200, transform: translateY(200px), so, the script will displace the div (200) +1px when you scroll the page...

Comment: Oh, now I get it, you increment and decrement `move` in there… No, you can't do that.

Comment: What do you mean? I literally did that, https://jsfiddle.net/zgwx4f8v/ the problem is that every time that I scroll up or down the div is displaced from the original position...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll events are not fired equidistantly (certainly not per pixel), and the number of scroll events for traversing a distance is not guaranteed by anything. A fast, short scroll will have less events than a slow, long scroll, while they might cover the same distance.

Since scrolling up and scrolling down are different from each other, a count (`move++`/`move--`) will get out of sync easily. Instead, you should always derive the displacement of your elements from the scroll position.

To keep the element in place, the derivation is simple: translate by exactly the scroll height. You could simply do `position:fixed` to achieve that though.

```js
const red = document.getElementById("red");
const pos = 200;

window.onscroll = function() {
  const move = pos + window.scrollY;
  red.style.transform = "translateY(" + move + "px)";
  red.innerHTML = move;
}
window.onscroll(); // init
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 1600px;background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(110, 155, 170, 0.5) 0%, rgba(110, 155, 170, 0.5) 25%,rgba(146, 183, 162, 0.5) 25%, rgba(146, 183, 162, 0.5) 50%,rgba(181, 211, 154, 0.5) 50%, rgba(181, 211, 154, 0.5) 75%,rgba(217, 239, 146, 0.5) 75%, rgba(217, 239, 146, 0.5) 100%),linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(30, 212, 152) 0%, rgb(30, 212, 152) 25%,rgb(62, 225, 150) 25%, rgb(62, 225, 150) 50%,rgb(93, 239, 148) 50%, rgb(93, 239, 148) 75%,rgb(125, 252, 146) 75%, rgb(125, 252, 146) 100%);padding: 1px">
  <div id="red" style="color:white;font-size:30px;background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(239, 52, 247, 0.45) 0%, rgba(239, 52, 247, 0.45) 25%,rgba(173, 76, 238, 0.45) 25%, rgba(173, 76, 238, 0.45) 50%,rgba(106, 101, 228, 0.45) 50%, rgba(106, 101, 228, 0.45) 75%,rgba(40, 125, 219, 0.45) 75%, rgba(40, 125, 219, 0.45) 100%),linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(31, 27, 249) 0%, rgb(31, 27, 249) 25%,rgb(96, 28, 250) 25%, rgb(96, 28, 250) 50%,rgb(161, 29, 250) 50%, rgb(161, 29, 250) 75%,rgb(226, 30, 251) 75%, rgb(226, 30, 251) 100%);width: 400px;height: 100px;margin: auto;transform: translateY(200px);"></div>
</div>
```

For a real parallax effect, you'd apply some function (like `/2`, `sin`, etc) to the scroll height.